# Cannot access file in assets subfolder

Tags: cocos2d-x, eclipse-cdt, cocos2d-x-3.0

As I mentioned in the title, when I load a music song named `music1.mp3` that stored in `assets/music/music1.mp3`. The logcat show `Fatal error 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000 (code 11)` and app gets force close. As far as I know, the `Fatal error 11` caused by accessing a NULL element or sth that have been already released. I've logged  `FileUtils::getInstance->getSearchPath()` and the result is `assets/music` as expected. But when I tried to log the path of `music1.mp3` in `getFullPathForFilename`, it only showed up `assets/music1.mp3` that make my app crash. Can anyone explain why it cannot access in assets subfolder (music) to find `music1.mp3` file? Sr for my bad english :D

P/s: my app runs perfecty in iOS.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Thank for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add search path to your FileUtil, as:

```
    FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchPath("SEARCH_PATH");
```

The other solution that I typically use is simply putting the full path in your loading routine. This will give you a very better understanding of what is going on and it also helps with consistency between Android and iOS:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playBackgroundMusic(
            "music/msc1.mp3", true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Kasra for reply.  Of course, I added all the search paths using the method you mentioned above but it still cannot find the file. And the same result if I put the full path to the file. It is too weird.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the exact same line that you use when you put the full address?

Comment: This might sound obvious, but anyways, you need to copy your music into your "resources" folder - not the "assets" folder. The "assets" folder is automatically managed and synced with the "resources" folder by cocos2d-x. If you copy anything into your assets folder and not the resource folder, when you compile the game, everything will be overwritten and you will lose your file that you had copied into assets folder.

Comment: I use these codes to set the search paths of my files:
`auto fileUtils = FileUtils::getInstance();
    std::vector<std::string> searchPaths;

    searchPaths.push_back("spine");
    searchPaths.push_back("sound");

    for (int i=0; i < searchPaths.size(); i++) {
        fileUtils->addSearchPath(searchPaths.at(i));
    }`
and with these codes it shows the right research paths that I've added above: 
`for (std::string s : fileUtils->getSearchPaths()) {
        log("%s", s.c_str());
    }`
logcat shows: `assets/spine` `assets/sound`

Comment: I also run the `build_native.py` to copy all my files from the `Resources` folder. I have checked `assets` folder and all my files are stored in their right paths.